# Connect with NVR to access stored videos

Tags: c++, python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a computer vision project where I want to process the videos captured by IP cameras in a mall. To do this!

- One possible way was to access the live stream of IP camera and process the stream. (I have done this successfully).
- But there are so many videos stored on drive of NVR which I also want to process.

One way to access those videos is using NVR's management software but this is a time consuming task. The question is, **Can I access those videos programmatically ?** May be using python, C++ or any other language. Any help or link would be highly appreciable.  Thanks.